# Are we required to use as few tags as possible?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw an edit to a question related to vue3 (javascript library), with these tags.

[image]

And then someone edited it to have fewer

[image]

Why? Isn't [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) related to [vuejs3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs3)? And [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is related, right? Isn't it to make sure that OP is using javascript, and not typescript?

Am I required to use as few tags as possible?

Comment: Leading question there. "One person did an edit to the effect of X" -> "Are we required to do X".

Comment: Also check the [[tag:router]] tag. The tag info says "*A router is a device that forwards data packets across multiple networks. DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS REGARDING URL ROUTING OR SINGLE PAGE APPLICATION ROUTERS*" [sic] - seems correct to be removed.

Comment: "Am I required to use as few tags as possible?" No, you are required to use useful tags. That's it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ouch... I'm more bothered by the inconsistent punctuation between the tags than the choice of tags themselves.

Anyway, some people think that language tags should be excluded from framework-specific questions even if they primarily involve code written in that language, to keep those questions away from users who are familiar with the language but not the framework. I'm not in that camp, and I respect their opinion, but it does cause some nasty fragmentation in questions as there's no consensus on whether framework-specific questions *should* all or not include language tags.

As for why [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and [vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-router) were removed, I guess the editor thinks only the most version-specific tags should be used. I can't say I agree with that either.

As for [router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router), it refers to network routers, not URL routing (I think this tag needs to be dealt with separately), so it doesn't belong.

You don't have to include as few tags in a question as possible, but you do want to ensure that the tags you use are all relevant to the question at hand. You don't have to use up all 5 tags either — don't add irrelevant filler tags just to boost the question's audience. (I'd be OK with keeping [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) because boosting the question's audience to Vue users in general seems reasonable to me.)

Comment: I don't remember where I read it, can't find the link atm, but there was a nice rule of thumb somewhere about each tag being able to be the _only_ tag on a question. It makes a good job addressing the "relevancy" factor for tagging.

Comment: @yivi: Yeah, I vaguely recall reading something like that too...

Comment: Apparently I've read it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/348149)

Comment: Re your second paragraph: the problem is that users (including yourself) think that tags are an all or nothing business. Either all questions that are tagged X should also be tagged Y or none at all. Reality is more nuanced. Only tag Y and X when both Y and X knowledge is required to answer the question. Good rule of thumb: if you can replace Y with any other tag, would the answer change? If the answer is no, you can safely remove the tag.